# how do i store difference between elements of an array into another array?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Suppose I have an integer array[2,5,10,25].Now I want to store the differences of these elements i.e 3,5,15 into another array using for loop.

```
System.out.println("6 entries");
        int[] arr=new int[6];
        System.out.println(" enter the numbers:");
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++) {
            arr[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

int[] diff=new int[5];
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
                diff[j]=(arr[i+1] - arr[i]);
                System.out.println(diff[j]);
            }

        }
```

This is what I have done

Comment: You don't need an inner loop, one loop is enough.

Comment: But then how will values be stored in the "diff" array

Comment: You can conclude what index to use in the `diff` array from only one loop. `diff[i] = arr[i+1]-arr[i]`, this will work if you keep your outer loop as it is

Comment: You are mixing indices here... As @JoakimDanielson says, only one is needed so as he suggests, get rid of the inner loop and change your index to `i` as follow: `diff[i] = arr[i+1] - arr[i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   diff[i-1] = arr[i] - arr[i-1];
   System.out.println(diff[i-1]);
}
```

This is what you need.

But let's see the problem with your code:

1. Nested loop is useless
2. `i+1` will throw `array index out of bound` exception when you try for last element in the array
3. And use `arr.length` instead a fixed hardcoded number.